# Ruby Tempfile vs File

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, filestream

I want to know the difference between `Tempfile`  and `File`.

I found that :

```
require 'open-uri'

open('c:/boot.ini'){|file|
  puts file.class  #File 
}

open('http://coderlee.cnblogs.com'){|file|
  puts file.class #Tempfile
}
```

and when I save the stream to a remote storage server,the `Tempfile` will cause an error,It seems that the reason is the encoding is not `ASCII-8BIT` why?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In the first case, **you are loading a file from your file system**. This create a File object, using the file name (it has one).

In the second case, **you are opening a stream toward a remote file**. There is no associated file on your file system, yet you need one if you want to make any operation on it. Thus, Ruby creates a [Tempfile](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-1.9.3/libdoc/tempfile/rdoc/Tempfile.html) for you with a unique filename that you don't even need to know (as the resource does not have a name itself). It then behave exactly like a File object.

Comment: Thanks for your answer,but how I make the Tempfile same as File,I mean the stream encoding.I found that the File stream encoding is  `ASCII-8BIT`,but the TempFile stream encoding is not `ASCII-8BIT`,I can upload file stream to third party storage server successfully,but the TempFile failed,I was tolled the data format is not right,what should I do? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The encoding of the document you retrieved is controlled by the server. If you want to retrieve the document in a different encoding, you need to change the encoding on the server.

Comment: my need is upload a remote file to a  cloud storage server ,but when I upload the stream `web_contents  = open('http://q.qlogo.cn/www.jpg') {|f| f.read}` I got a `400 Bad Request` but when the stream is  `web_contents = params[:upfile]` ,It is ok!why?thanks